# In Sublime Text 3: is there a shortcut to remove blank lines in a selected text? (same for blanks in a line)

Tags: sublimetext3

My question is very simple:

Is there a shortcut in Sublime Text 3 which allows to remove blank lines in a selected text? (same for blanks in a line)

For instance, how to make this text:

```
a

b

c
```

To become:

```
a
b
c
```

And this line:

```
I need to remove these blanks.
```

to become this line:

`Ineedtoremovetheseblanks`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You don't need a plugin to do this, a simple regex search and replace will do. First, select the text where you'd like to delete the blank lines. Then, select **`Find → Replace…`** (or, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on OS X). Make sure the "Regular Expression" and "In selection" buttons are selected:

[image: find/replace dialog]

In `Find What:`, enter `^\n`, and make sure the `Replace With:` field is empty. Then, simply hit "Replace All" and this:

[image: before replace]

becomes this:

[image: after replace]

As a bit of explanation, the regular expression `^\n` searches for the beginning of a line (`^`) immediately followed by a newline character (`\n`). If you suspect that some of your "blank" lines contain whitespace, like space or tab characters, you can use `^\s*\n` instead - `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace characters, including newline characters.

For your second example, use the same Find/Replace settings as above, except your regular expression should simply be `\s*`.

Comment: `^\s*\n` worked for me as it contained white spaces.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC you saved my time! this is perfect solution!

Comment: You can easily find all empty lines along with whitespace ones: `^[\s]*?[\n\r]+`

Answer (score 18):

There is a package called [Trimmer](https://github.com/jonlabelle/Trimmer). You can install it via Package control.

After you got the package you can use its functionalities. Just highlight the text you want to change (or don't select anything if you want to change the entire file) and then choose:

1) Edit > Line > Delete Empty Lines

2) Edit > Line > Remove Blank Spaces

Alternatively, as Chris's answer already pointed out you can use the classic search & replace functionality that is already present in the editor.

Comment: My answer would have worked but for the fact op wanted to only remove the blank lines within the selection which the search and replace doesn't seem to be able to do. Package found to do it though so my answer has been re-written to reflect.

Comment: Very Good Package , to easily remove the empty and trailing space... +1 for time saving plugin mention

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 4):

AS my original answer was incorrect, I have found this package which will be suitable for your needs.

The package is called DeleteBlankLines, for Sublime Text 3, has the ability to delete blank lines for the entire document and within the selected text only, all from a key stroke just like you were after.

The package can be found here:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DeleteBlankLines

Comment: Thanks, but I can only delte ALL the blank lines of the file with it, and I want to delete only the selected ones

Comment: Just found out my original answer was completely wrong but have found another. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `\s+`, which will get one or more (i.e., the `+` character) whitespace characters (i.e., the `\s` escape sequence).

The `*` character will do *zero* or more, which on some versions can break up the individual words into letters.